# Unable to Access Elasticsearch Server on Render.com from External Applications

Tags: elasticsearch, render.com

I have set up Elasticsearch on Render.com for my startup hosting by following the instructions provided in the article "Deploy Elasticsearch" available at https://render.com/docs/deploy-elasticsearch. The setup process went smoothly, but I am facing an issue where I am unable to access the Elasticsearch server from external applications. It appears that the Elasticsearch service is private and not accessible from outside.

I need to find a solution that allows me to access the Elasticsearch server from other applications inside of Render.com. Is there a recommended approach or configuration that would enable external access to the Elasticsearch server on Render.com?

I expected to be able to access the Elasticsearch server from external applications, but I'm currently unable to do so due to its private nature.

I'm seeking advice on how to enable external access to the Elasticsearch server hosted on Render.com so that I can utilize it in other applications. Any suggestions, recommended configurations, or alternative methods to achieve this would be greatly appreciated